# Usage of 'than' in the sentence

Tags: grammar

> You should have had more respect for him and for me than to fear what you had feared.

The above statement is from a novel.I couldn't understand what 'than' means in the statement?

Comment: The following sources may prove helpful: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/230545/determining-if-than-is-used-as-conjunction-or-preposition                 https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/than

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would read this as there being an implied "rather".

> You should have had more respect for him and for me [rather] than to fear what you had feared.